# How can I speed up my slow query?

Tags: mysql, time-series-database

I have a table of **pigeon** data.
**pigeon_id** = ID of pigeon
**date_time** = time of signal_event
**pigeon_station** = id of pigeon station
**signal_strength** = signal strength of pigeon

```
    CREATE TABLE `pigeon_signal` (
  `pigeon_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `signal_strength` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `pigeon_station` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index1` (`pigeon_id`,`pigeon_station`),
  KEY `index2` (`pigeon_id`,`date_time`,`pigeon_station`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table count: 500,000 rows

Each pigeon has a transmitter. Every few seconds the pigeon station records the signal strength of all the surrounding pigeons.

I want to query the first time a pigeon station sees a pigeon. Here is my sql. It is slow but it returns the correct results:

```
select ps2.* from pigeon_signal as ps join
 (select MIN(date_time) as date_time, pigeon_id, pigeon_station from pigeon_signal group by pigeon_id, pigeon_station) ps2
 on ps.date_time = ps2.date_time and ps.pigeon_id = ps2.pigeon_id and
 ps.pigeon_station = ps2.pigeon_station
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED:
[image]

The query takes about 2 seconds to run (too long).
Is there a better way of querying this data?
I would appreciate any tips/hints/advice related to this problem.

Many thanks :D

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the answers!! :D
I have changed the pigeon_id column to a varchar(20).

@ypercubeᵀᴹ I changed the index to what you suggested and it is the fastest (thanks!!!)  But why?

distinct pigeon_id:      25306
distinct pigeon_station: 36
distinct date_time:      452322

My thinking: Order the index attributes by the number of distinct elems ascending. Results:
1. pigeon_station,pigeon_id, date_time:  1.8 seconds
2. pigeon_id, pigeon_station, date_time: 0.4 seconds
3. pigeon_id,date_time,pigeon_station:   1.8 seconds
4. date_time, pigeon_id, pigeon_station: 1.9 seconds

Why is option 2 faster than option 1? As there are less distinct pigeon_station values than pigeon_id.
But if the optimal index should order the attributes by the number of distinct values descending then why isn't option 4 the fastest?

Many thanks for your time

Comment: `pigeon_id` is `varchar(200)`? Why?

Comment: Your query would benefit from an index on `(pigeon_id, pigeon_station, date_time)`. Replace your `index1` with the above index.

Comment: And if you don't need the "signal_strength" in the output, the simpler query woul do: `select MIN(date_time) as date_time, pigeon_id, pigeon_station from pigeon_signal group by pigeon_id, pigeon_station ;`

Comment: On top, make a database. Tables for Pidgeon and Station, integer ID's referencing the central signal table. You waste space with the varchars, which means more IO and a lot more processing for string comparisons.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably a pigeon cannot arrive at a station twice in one second?  Then add this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(pigeon_id, pigeon_station, date_time)
```

This will improve on ypercube's suggestion, perhaps by a factor of 2.

At that point, probably both of your indexes become useless.  But before that, let's see the other important queries.